# cyrillic with newtx changed from scalable to bitmap

Tags: cyrillic, newtx, russian

Feeding

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
\foreignlanguage{russian}{%
  \fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont%%% using this line has no effect.
  %\CYRL\cyre\cyro\cyrn\cyri\cyrd\ \CYRV\cyri\cyrt\cyra\cyrl\cyrsftsn\cyre\cyrv\cyri\cyrch\ \CYRK\cyra\cyrn\cyrt\cyro\cyrr\cyro\cyrv\cyri\cyrch%%% or same as
  Леонид Витальевич Канторович%
}
\end{document}
```

to https://texlive.net/run now, on 2022-08-03, or to the TeX Live in Debian stable from 4 May 2022 yields a version with scalable fonts:

[image: scalable, good output]

whereas feeding the same input to `pdflatex` from the current TeX Live in Debian yields a version with, I think, bitmap fonts:

[image: bitmap, bad output]

Clearly, the first (IMHO, scalable) output is preferable, whereas the coarseness of the second output sometimes manifests itself in an unpleasant way.  Which change has caused  this deterioration? Why has it been it done?  Any simple switch or command to get the scalable Russian/Cyrillic fonts back in Debian (ideally without loading extra packages)?

Versions I used in Debian:

- `texlive` package version: 2021.20211217-1
- pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.1.7)
- LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
- L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
- standalone 2018/03/26 v1.3a
- fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v
- inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d
- babel 2021/11/29 3.67
- russianb.ldf 2021/01/10 1.3m
- ngerman 2021/02/27 v2.13
- ngermanb 2021/02/27 v2.13
- newtxtext 2021/10/13 v1.658

Comment: this is determined by the map files, not by anything in the tex document

Comment: I get `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape \`T2A/ntxtlf/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using \`T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 11.` that is, no cyrillic newtx so it falls back to computer modern.

Comment: you need the cm-super fonts.

Comment: Do you need to set the T2A font encoding stuff explicitly? E.g., does `\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  \usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}\usepackage{newtxtext} \begin{document} \foreignlanguage{russian}{Леонид Витальевич Канторович} \end{document}` compile correctly and employ vector fonts on your system? For sure, on my system (MacOS 12.5 "Monterey", MacTeX2022, pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24, LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5), this little test document compiles flawlessly. Do note that you'll be getting CM-Super, not a Times Roman clone.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Got scalable fonts after having installed the Debian package `cm-super`.  It would have probably never occurred to me if you hadn't mentioned it. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yep, got the same Warning.

Comment: @Mico Without T2A and without cm-super, I get bitmap fonts. Without T2A and with cm-super, I get scalable fonts. So, what's the difference between having T2A and not having it, from the point of the user? The resulting PDF seems to be the same up to dates, times, and ID.

Comment: so the newtx part of your question is not relevant, that is doing nothing other than generate a warning that it is not being used

Comment: @Mico  Yes, I see I get a Computer-Modern–like font. Any way to get a Times-like one instead?

Comment: `\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont` does nothing as babel has already selected T2A as part of  `\foreignlanguage{russian}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. I mentioned newtx as well as ngerman, I guess, so as to tell the readers which fonts and which language I typically use for the main text (apart from the name of a Russian mathematician).

Comment: `find /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex -name t2a\*.fd` shows you the fonts available in t2a (limited choice) you would have far wider choice from luatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle @Mico Oh, I see. Without loading T2A, babel complains: `Package babel Warning: No Cyrillic font encoding has been loaded so far.
(babel)                A font encoding should be declared before babel.
(babel)                Default \`T2A' encoding will be loaded  on input line 78.`

Comment: you need t2a encoded fonts, you just don't need `\fontencoding{T2A}\selectfont` as babel is doing that already

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. For my stock Debian installation, the location is a bit different; `find /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex -name t2a\*.fd` prints a list of 35 files in the subdirectories antt, iwona, miama, xcharter, gentium-tug, cyrillic, cmsrb, tempora, kurier, and cm-lgc. Is any of them a Times-like font that I could use instead of a Computer-modern–like font from cm-super?

Comment: yes the debian system tex is installed in /usr/share, tug texlive installs in /usr/local/texlive/<year>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitmap Cyrillic fonts mean that you have an incomplete TeX distribution lacking the CM-Super fonts. But mixing CM with a Times clone is not the best.

On the other hand, the NewTX fonts don't support Cyrillic, but it's not difficult to tell `pdflatex` to use a compatible font family that does, namely Tempora, just for the Russian parts.

This requires LaTeX released February 2020 or later.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{\rmdefault}{Tempora-TLF}%
}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{russian}{Леонид Витальевич Канторович}

\textit{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Леонид Витальевич Канторович}}

\textbf{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Леонид Витальевич Канторович}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

We need `\AtBeginDocument` because `newtxtext` delays the redefinition of `\rmdefault` until the very last moment.

Just to see that the fonts match, here's the output of

```
eo\textsc{h}\foreignlanguage{russian}{еон}
```

[image]

The small caps h is a bit wider than н, but it's not really a problem.

Comment: Thx! I heard that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is no longer necessary, being a default. Is this true? I prefer to have some kind of documentation (mainly, to myself) saying that the input is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @GeekestGeek Yes, it has been the default for a few years. If your input is not UTF-8 you can still set the encoding with `inputenc`.

Comment: Good! Btw., even `\textit{\textbf{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Леонид Витальевич Канторович}}}` works now.

Comment: However, `\textsc{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Леонид Витальевич Канторович}}` fails with “! No declaration for shape T2A/Tempora-TLF/m/sc.”. How to specify a default font for small-capitals Cyrillic, with a Times-like font being the default for the rest of Cyrillic?

Comment: @GeekestGeekFind a suitable font. But are yiu sure yiu want small caps for Cyrillic?

Comment: Unfortunately, small caps in Russian-language setting unexpectedly occur when you say `url={…},langid={russian}` in an entry of your bibliography file and run biblatex. Then, I think, “URL” is typeset in small caps. Ideally, it should be, of course, not “URL” but a translation of “URL”, such as “Адрес:”, or “URL” should be typeset in English. As of now, I simply circumvented of the problem by saying `langid={USenglish}` instead of `langid={russian}`.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in a comment,

> Yes, I see I get a Computer-Modern–like font. Any way to get a Times-like one instead?

I'm not all that familiar with Debian, but I think your best bet is to switch from either pdfLaTeX to either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, to employ the `fontspec` package, and to use a system font that (a) is close to Times Roman and (b) features Cyrillic glyphs.

E.g., my system (MacOS 12.5 "Monterey", MacTeX2022) features a system font called "Times New Roman". Compiling the test code shown below under LuaLaTeX, I get the following screenshot:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
  \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}  
  \usepackage{newtxtext} % lacks easy-to-access Cyrilic glyphs, sadly
\else
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{Times New Roman} % choose an available font with Cyrillic glyphs
\fi

\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel} 

\begin{document} 
\foreignlanguage{russian}{Леонид Витальевич Канторович} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually there *is* a package `tempora` (also by Michael Sharpe) providing Greek and Cyrillic fonts matching `newtx` .

Comment: @campa - Thanks. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the `tempora` package. Is it a substitute for `newtx`, or maybe a complement?

Comment: It's a complement, but I should look into it. I distinctly remember that the MWE provided in the `tempora` documentation didn't work, because `newtx` sets some fonts in a nasty `\AtEndPreamble` hook.

Comment: Thanks! In non-minimal example, I also use UTF-8-based engines (and do something else in that case anyway). The command `\ifpdftext` is new to me. Which conditional branch is taken if you compile with `latex` to produce a .dvi file?